# React-native ERROR: In <declare-styleable> FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings

Tags: android, react-native

ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:fontVariationSettings
ERROR: In  FontFamilyFont, unable to find attribute android:ttcIndex

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-push-notification:processReleaseResources'.

  > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 1):

After trying a lot of solutions, Finally it did the trick for me.

1. Downgrade your react-native-push-notification version to '2.0.1'
2. Add these lines in android/build.gradle

allprojects {

```
repositories {
   ...
}

configurations.all {

        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { 
         DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
           if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
               details.useVersion '15.0.0'
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

3. Finally, run react-native run-android. And you are good to go.....

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days struggle i found the solution, I have tried many solution from internet, But only few of them are required to solve this.  Below are the steps which helped me to solve this.

1. Take a back up of your project
2. First you need to upgrade `react-native` to `v0.59.9`, And `react` to `v16.8.5`. you can follow the [Steps](https://medium.com/@shreyasnisal/upgrading-to-react-native-v0-59-ddb8f6804b17) for Upgrading react-native

2.Upgrade all necesary modules

3.Make sure you have replaced all necessary things in `MainApplication.java` & `AndroidManifest.xml`

4.You need to add `googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"` & `firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"` in your `android/build.gradle`

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+" // < = Add this
        firebaseVersion = "17.3.4" // < = Add this
    }
```

Then re-build `react-native run-android`